# Cant able to apply soft assertion in loop(karate.repeat) in karate. Normally soft assertion is working but not for the loop

Tags: karate

def fun = function(i){karate.call('classpath:base.feature',{ req: requestMap[i]})} karate.repeat(numberOfRequests,fun)

In base.feature file, i am using "match A contains B" at somewhere. How would i continue the iteration of the loop and complete all the iteration even after the failure of any iteration?

I tried using:

- configure continueOnStepFailure = true

Above line is working for simple steps written in a single feature file,
But its not working for loop(i am calling other feature file via loop as you can see above). After the first failed iteration, the loop is breaking.

Comment: you can leave aside `continueOnStepFailure` I don't think it solves your issue. look at the other options provided in the linked answer. for example instead of a loop, if you use the `@setup` annotation mentioned here - you can achieve what you want: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup - if you still don't find a solution, you may need to look for some other tool, or contribute code